# Add up safe navigation array lengths

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a count that starts at 0:

```
let count = 0;
```

And then I'm also getting several arrays which may or may not exist on an object and I wish to add these to the count:

```
count += currentData?.subjects?.length + currentData?.delivery_method?.length
```

I'm using the safe navigation operator since they may or may not exist.
However when I return the count:

```
return count;
```

I'm getting NaN (Not a number). How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `NaN` because whenever one of the values is not defined, you add `undefined` to `count`.

You should default the values to `0`:

```
count += currentData?.subjects?.length ?? 0;
count += currentData?.delivery_method?.length ?? 0;
```